# Efficient checking for NULL pointers in function called millions of times

Tags: c

I am adding a function to a library which is expected to be called millions of times. What would be the most efficient way to check if the function is passed a NULL pointer and exit if it is and continue if not given that it is expected that the pointer passed will be non-NULL most of the time. Any pointers would be welcome ...

Thanks

Comment: You can check pointer by `if (!ptr)..return...else..do something`.

Comment: I know this, my focus is on the term *efficient*

Comment: can you tell me how much efficiency you want?  It already efficient way to do it.

Comment: Have you been able to show that the `if (!ptr)..return...else..do something` is inefficient for your case? As BS said: "First measure, **then** optimize"

Comment: in these cases, ALWAYS write down and test the simplest way first.

Comment: If your primary focus is efficiency, you should rather make sure you never call your function with a NULL pointer instead of checking for it.

Comment: optimizing the function will not change the result too much, but design approach will. keep that in mind.

Comment: Depending on your compiler (which is typically designated for a specific architecture), you might have a directive telling the optimizer to assume that an `if` occurs more frequently than its corresponding `else`. What platform are you developing for?

Comment: Millions of times, you say? You mean that if you spend one cycle too many in the function, it could make your program slower by several milliseconds!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU C compiler has a [`__builtin_expect`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fexpect-3668) to tell the optimizer the most probable outcome of a value.

It is not standard C though.

You can `#define` macros to wrap around it and conditionally switch which definition to use, based on the compiler.

Linux kernel uses it this way (include/linux/compiler.h):

```
#define likely(x)      __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)    __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
```

The `ifs` then become:

```
if (likely(an_expression)) { ... } 

if (unlikely(another_expression)) { ... }
```

Comment: However it should be pointed out that on x86, `__builtin_expect` is at best compiled to `cs:` and `ds:` prefixes for conditional jumps, which are ignored by modern processors with this instruction set. See section 3.16 in http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf (look for “Branch hint prefixes have no effect”)

Comment: Thanks rslemos, I something similar to this ...